# How to make buttons run code on correct row after sorting the rows?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet where the rows are individual projects and the columns are the information about of that project.

The columns I am dealing with are for a technician to make a service call so I have: Tech Name, Site Contact, Date, Time and duration.

In the next column I have a button that once clicked, will run my VBA code to generate a meeting request that is sent to that technician which also placed the event on my outlook calendar. This code has been proven and is fine.

I generated buttons for about 300 rows. Upon a click, the code SHOULD check the button's location with the Application.Caller and get row and column numbers which I use to pull info for the meeting request.

Initially the button press works.

The issue is that I have the sheet set to auto sort with AutoFilter.ApplyFilter. So when I enter a job a row 92 with associated button 92 and the row auto sorts to say 30, the button 30 now tries to schedule 31 and button 92 is now scheduling row 30 (not sure where the button that schedules row 30 goes).

When clicked, the button should be reporting the cell directly under it.

Code to create buttons:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub CreateButtons()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Projects")

Dim BTN As Button
Dim btn1 As Range
Dim btn2 As Range
Dim btn3 As Range

Dim i As Long
For i = 2 To 95
    Set btn1 = ws.Cells(i, 22)
        Set BTN = ws.Buttons.Add(btn1.Left, btn1.Top, btn1.Width, btn1.Height)
            With BTN
                .Caption = "Schedule" & i
                .OnAction = "TASKSCHEDULER"
            End With

    Set btn2 = ws.Cells(i, 31)
        Set BTN = ws.Buttons.Add(btn2.Left, btn2.Top, btn2.Width, btn2.Height)
            With BTN
                .Caption = "Schedule"
                .OnAction = "TASKSCHEDULER"
            End With

    Set btn3 = ws.Cells(i, 40)
        Set BTN = ws.Buttons.Add(btn3.Left, btn3.Top, btn3.Width, btn3.Height)
            With BTN
                .Caption = "Schedule"
                .OnAction = "TASKSCHEDULER"
            End With
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Code for Button Click:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub TASKSCHEDULER()

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Projects")

Dim b As Object
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long
Set b = ws.Buttons(Application.Caller)
    With b.TopLeftCell
        r = .Row
        c = .Column
    End With

Dim TECH As String
Dim sitecon As String
Dim connum As String
Dim schdate As String
Dim schtime As String
Dim schdur As String

If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(r, c - 8)) Then 'VerIfy data has been entered into all fields needed - works
    TECH = "Technician" & vbCrLf
Else
    TECH = vbNullString
End If
If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(r, c - 5)) Then
    sitecon = "Site Contact" & vbCrLf
Else
    sitecon = vbNullString
End If
If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(r, c - 4)) Then
    connum = "Site Contact Phone #" & vbCrLf
Else
    connum = vbNullString
End If
If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(r, c - 3)) Then
    schdate = "Date" & vbCrLf
Else
    schdate = vbNullString
End If
If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(r, c - 2)) Then
    schtime = "Start Time" & vbCrLf
Else
    schtime = vbNullString
End If
If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(r, c - 1)) Then
    schdur = "Duration" & vbCrLf
Else
    schdur = vbNullString
End If 'End field verify

If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(r, c - 7)) Or IsEmpty(ws.Cells(r, c - 5)) Or IsEmpty(ws.Cells(r, c - 4)) Or IsEmpty(ws.Cells(r, c - 3)) Or IsEmpty(ws.Cells(r, c - 2)) Or IsEmpty(ws.Cells(r, c - 1)) Then 'Call out missing fields If present
        MsgBox "Missing Fields: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & TECH & sitecon & connum & schdate & schtime & schdur
    Else
        SCHMTG     'Schedule Meeting
    End If
'Else
    'CNCLMTG   'Cancel Meeting

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try shrinking your button a bit so it fits more accurately within the underlying cell space:

`Set BTN = ws.Buttons.Add(btn1.Left+2, btn1.Top+2, btn1.Width-4, btn1.Height-4)`

Comment: The fact that this works makes my head hurt and THANK YOU! The logic of what it was doing wasn't making any sense. The fact that the button wasn't moving when the row sorted but was still performing the function based on the row's new location was blowing my mind. It was supposed to read its current row and do the function for the row it was currently on.